# How do I split a combo in osu?

Tags: osu

I did like 20 circles in one single combo, and I want to split it into many different combos.

[image]

Is there a way to do that?

EDIT: I don't want to erase the circles, I just want to set one of these circles as the start of a new combo (or color).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click while placing circles will change the colour/combo of the circles, Its nice to see more people making beatmaps on osu :D

Comment: I'm glad about it too. Btw, I'm asking how to change the colors of the circles that I already set. I don't want to erase my whole work just to reput them in different colors. :c

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the editor has a button which forces the start of a new combo. You might need to re-place a few notes, though.